Why percent (%) sign is not encoding when I send it in query string
I am sending GET requests from Postman to Nginx server which is gateway for my backend app.
My requests can contain filter query parameter which is an array of objects:
[{"property":"text_prop","operator":"ilike","value":"dep"}]
In the Nginx server's logs I can see that it receives this filter as:
[{%22property%22:%22text_prop%22,%22operator%22:%22ilike%22,%22value%22:%22dep%22}] where double quotes has been encoded according to Percent encoding rules.
Next, I add % sing to value: [{"property":"text_prop","operator":"ilike","value":"dep%"}] . At Nginx logs that construction received as: [{%22property%22:%22text_prop%22,%22operator%22:%22ilike%22,%22value%22:%22dep%%22}] - that extra percent sign has not been encoded to %25 and has been send in a raw form %22dep%%22.
Why is the percent sign not encoded automatically - I tried sending requests from Postman and from the Chrome browser? Perhaps somewhere there is a condition that the percent sign is not automatically encoded and it ALWAYS needs to be encoded manually (% -> %25) - but I did not find this in various descriptions of the Percent encoding standard?
All other characters are encoded automatically in my case, with the only exception being the percent sign.
